# Chrome mysteriously lowers SVG position by 2px

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, safari, background-position

I'm trying to make a bunch of image links from an SVG spritesheet I have, but I'm running into cross-browser problems between Chrome and Safari and Firefox.
I have a bunch of  tags like this:

```
<a href="#" id="twitter-logo" class="socialIcon"></a>
<a href="#" id="facebook-logo" class="socialIcon"></a>
```

Then in my css I set up the background image for all of them

```
.socialIcons{
    background-image: url('../img/social.svg');
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#twitter-logo{background-position: 0px 0px;}
#twitter-logo:hover{background-position: 0px -200px;}
#facebook-logo{background-position: -79px 0px}
#facebook-logo:hover{background-position: -79px -200px;}
```

This works fine in both Firefox and Safari, but in chrome it appears that the SVG file is 2 pixels higher than in the others. What that means is that the top of my icons are 2 pixels below the top of my `<a>`, and the my icons are cut off 2px from the edge. To fix this I can subtract 2 from each of the background-position y-values, but then I have problems because they're now wrong in Safari and Firefox.

Where is this mysterious shift coming from?

Comment: What does your SVG look like?  Can you make a sample fiddle so we can see?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue come up. In our SVG the height was set to 165.745px. Once I updated those values to 166px everything looked right in all the browsers.

So, it would seem it stems from the difference in how browsers round floats into integers. This is consistent with the issue of trying to float a lot of percentage-based elements around each other in a responsive layout... Chrome/IE tends to add a pixel or 2, at times where FF doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for now, Chrome and IE has the same y position, while firefox and safari has the same.

Firefox cant read "background-position-y" which IE and Chrome Can. So fix it like this:

background-position: -177px -70px; //firefox fix on y-position

background-position-y: -72px;

IE and Chrome will read the last line and overwrite the y-value in the first line, I have still not found any other fix.

Cheers

Eduardo